# Custom environment that outputs a tabularx generates an error only if the etoolbox package is included

Tags: macros, environments, tabularx, multicolumn, etoolbox

I'm dealing with a really complex table and I want to define an environment with some additional macros in order to make the table creation code more semantic. So far I've defined the environment and the macros and it seems that they work but once i put them in my main document I get some strange errors. I investigated further and it seems that the error is caused by the `etoolbox` package. Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{etoolbox}


\title{MyTitle}
\author{MyAuthor}

\newenvironment{scenario}[1]
   { \newcommand{\entry}[1]{Number. & Test & ##1\\\hline}
    \tabularx{\linewidth}{|c|c|X|}
    \hline 
    \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{#1}\\
    \hline}
   {\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{}\\
    \hline
    \endtabularx}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{MySection}
\subsection{MySubSection}

\begin{scenario}{Title}
    \entry{Hello LaTeX.SX}
    \entry{if i include the etoolbox package i get an error.}
\end{scenario}

\end{document}
```

This is the xelatex output:

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.999991 (TeX Live 2019/Debian) (preloaded format=xelatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./wewe.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 2
L3 programming layer <2020-02-14>
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size12.clo))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/tabularx.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/array.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-xdvipdfmx.def)
(./wewe.aux) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd)
! Misplaced \omit.
\multispan ->\omit 
                   \@multispan 
l.28 \end{scenario}
                   
? ! Misplaced \span.
\sp@n ->\span 
              \omit \advance \@multicnt \m@ne 
l.28 \end{scenario}
                   
? ! Misplaced \omit.
\sp@n ->\span \omit 
                    \advance \@multicnt \m@ne 
l.28 \end{scenario}
                   
? ! Misplaced \span.
\sp@n ->\span 
              \omit \advance \@multicnt \m@ne 
l.28 \end{scenario}
                   
? ! Misplaced \omit.
\sp@n ->\span \omit 
                    \advance \@multicnt \m@ne 
l.28 \end{scenario}
                   
? ! Misplaced \noalign.
\hline ->\noalign 
                  {\ifnum 0=`}\fi \hrule \@height \arrayrulewidth \futurelet...
l.28 \end{scenario}
                   
? 
Overfull \hbox (0.4pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 28--28
[]|

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 28--28

[1] (./wewe.aux) )
Output written on wewe.pdf (1 page).
Transcript written on wewe.log.
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Try updating your TeX Live. I ran this through several versions, starting from TeX Live 2020 your MWE doesn't cause any errors. I suggest using vanilla TeX Live 2021 (or TeX Live 2021 from Debian unstable) instead of the out-of-date TeX Live 2019.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `etoolbox` included in TeX Live 2019 introduces problems with the `end` part of environments when `\multicolumn` is at the beginning.

You can work around the issue using `\NewEnviron`, but you should really upgrade your TeX Live.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{environ}

\title{MyTitle}
\author{MyAuthor}

\NewEnviron{scenario}[1]
 {%
  \newcommand{\entry}[1]{Number. & Test & ##1\\\hline}%
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|c|c|X|}
  \hline 
  \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{#1}\\
  \hline
  \BODY
  \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{}\\
  \hline
  \end{tabularx}
 }

\begin{document}

\begin{scenario}{Title}
    \entry{Hello LaTeX.SX}
    \entry{if i include the etoolbox package i get an error.}
\end{scenario}

\end{document}
```