# tabularx package compatibility for question 408900 (Protocol)

Tags: tabularx, glossaries, datetime, parskip, autonum

In the question [How can make a protocol in latex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/408900/how-can-make-a-protocol-in-latex)
there is an interesting solution given by [Werner](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5764/werner). The problem is that if you try to insert it in a document using one (just one) of the following packages:

- \usepackage{autonum}
- \usepackage{parskip}
- \usepackage{glossaries}
- \usepackage{glossaries-extra}
- \usepackage{datetime}
- \usepackage{forest}
- \usepackage{smartdiagram}

then you get the following error:

> ! Misplaced \noalign. \hline ->\noalign
> {\ifnum 0=`}\fi \hrule @height \arrayrulewidth \futurelet...
> l.61 \end{protocol}

(adding one of the lines above before \usepackage{tabularx} in the given solution and compiling will give you the error, comment it out, it works nicely).
Because the error is always the same, maybe somebody who knows well these packages can see the reason why and a workaround?

Comment: Please provide a full [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) which reproduces the error.

Comment: The problem is with etoolbox (which is loaded by all your packages). It fails in texlive 2019 but works in texlive 2020 and newer. The best is to update your system, see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/620181/2388

Comment: About Marv comment: In this case, I am not convince that you need a MWE, the solution to the question is the code of the solution given by Werner (the link is provided) and as written you just add one of the use package line and you reproduce the error.

Comment: Ulrike answer should be considered as the answer (I will accept it as the answer if it is moved from comment to answer). However the idea of updating the system will not work here because the compilation is done in overleaf where you do not really manage the system.

Comment: On Overleaf, you can switch to a more recent TL than 2019 in the settings.

Comment: To change the setting in Overleaf, just click on Menu and then choose 2021 in TeX Live version drop-down menu.